# How to change window location in js function, polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a script at the bottom of my template:

```js
 _checkInput: function(event) {
        let params;
        params = null;
        params = {
          start: this.start,
          end: this.end,
          title: this.title
        };

        if (params === null) {
          alert("Input is required.")
        } else {
          this.$.splitter.params = params;
          var path = window.location.href;
          console.log(path);
          path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'))
          console.log('Redirecting to: ' + path);
          this.$.splitter.execute().then(this.set("route.path", path));
        }
      },
```

What I'd like to do here is figure out the path and then do the equivalent of a window.location to that path, whihc I've read is setting the route.path. The path is correct, I have confirmed, but it doesn't seem that the this.set("route.path" is not taking effect as the window location remains the same. Is there a correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined `<app-route>`?

Comment: Because you are modifying a sub-property on an object (route.path), you need to use the Polymer method "notifyPath". The reason for this, is that modifying a sub property is a non-obsrvable change.